# Upload video to firebase through Nodejs but bytelength error coming

Tags: node.js, typescript, firebase, firebase-storage

I am trying to create a Nodejs Server that uploads the video to firebase storage and images to Cloudinary but there is an error happening when I am creating temp files it stores images to Cloudinary but shows an *bytelength error*:

[image: bytelength error (click to see the error stacktrace)]

This data is coming from the client

[image: This data is coming from the client (image)] how to solve it

```
/* Index.ts */

import "dotenv/config";
import "./configs/init_mongodb";
import express, { Request, Response, Application } from "express";
import cors from "cors";
import verifyAuthor from "./middleware/verifyAuthor";
import bodyParser from "body-parser";
import morgan from "morgan";
import upload from "express-fileupload";
import adminRouter from "./routes/admin";

const app: Application = express();

app.use(express.json());
app.use(cors());
app.use(morgan("dev"));
app.use(upload(
  {
    useTempFiles: true,
  }
));

app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

app.get("/admin", verifyAuthor, (req: Request, res: Response) => {
  res.send("Admin Page");
});

app.use("/admin", verifyAuthor, adminRouter);

app.get("/client", verifyAuthor, (req: Request, res: Response) => {
  res.send("Client Page");
});

app.listen(process.env.PORT || 5000, () => {
  console.log(`Server is running on port ${process.env.PORT || 5000}`);
});
```

---

This is where I send the video file to the firebase storage

```
/* firebase.ts */
import firebaseStorageConfig from "../configs/firebaseConfig";
import {
  getDownloadURL,
  ref,
  uploadBytes,
  deleteObject,
} from "firebase/storage";
import { v4 } from "uuid";

// upload video to firebase storage

export const uploadVideo = async (video: any) => {
  const storageRef = ref(firebaseStorageConfig, `videos/${v4()}`);

  // this is when temp file is not created

  // await uploadBytes(storageRef, video.data, {
  //   contentType: video.mimetype,
  // });


  // this is when temp file is created
  await uploadBytes(storageRef, video.tempFilePath, {
    contentType: video.mimetype,
  });

  const videoUrl = await getDownloadURL(storageRef);

  return videoUrl;
};

// delete files from firebase storage

export const deleteFiles = async () => {
  try {
    const storageRef = ref(firebaseStorageConfig);
    await deleteObject(storageRef);
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
};
```

---

This is where I am calling the uploadVideo function

```
// admin.ts
import express, { NextFunction, Request, Response } from "express";
import { uploadVideo } from "../helpers/firebase";
import { uploadImage } from "../helpers/cloudnary";
import { deleteFiles } from "../helpers/delfiles";
import { insertData } from "../helpers/mongoDb";
import { v4 } from "uuid";

const router = express.Router();

const saveData = async (req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction) => {
  try {
    console.log(req.files);

    const video: any = req.files?.video;
    const image: any = req.files?.image;

    const videoUrl = await uploadVideo(video);

    const imageUrl = await uploadImage(image);

    const linksBody = [...req.body.links];
    const linkLen = linksBody.length;
    const links = [];
    if (linkLen > 0) {
      console.log("body", linksBody);
      if (linkLen === 1) {
        links.push(JSON.parse(linksBody[0]));
      } else {
        linksBody.map((link: any) => {
          links.push(JSON.parse(link));
        });
      }
    }

    const tags = req.body.tags.split(",").trim();

    console.log("tags", tags);

    const data = {
      id: v4(),
      projectName: req.body.projectName,
      projectDescription: req.body.about,
      otherUrls: links,
      projectVideoUrl: videoUrl,
      projectImageUrl: imageUrl,
      projectTags: tags,
    };

    const portfolio_data = await insertData(data);

    deleteFiles();
    res.status(200).send({ status: "Ok", data: portfolio_data });
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
    next(err);
  }
};

router.post("/save", saveData);

export default router;
```

---

EDIT:

(Solution of this problem)

When I am send the image and video from client to server and express-fileupload change buffer to tmp file
changing the tmp file into buffer format
using the following code and use that buffer to upload to firebase storage

```
fs.readFile(video.tempFilePath, async function (err, buffer) {
  if (err) throw err;
  console.log(buffer);
  video.data = buffer;
  videoUrl = await uploadVideo(video);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You must pass the actual file in `uploadBytes()` but `video.tempFilePath` is a string. Try:

```
import fs from 'fs';

export const uploadVideo = async (video: any) => {
  const file = video.data;
   
  // Alternatively, try reading file like this 
  // const file = fs.readFileSync(video.tempFilePath);
  
  const storageRef = ref(firebaseStorageConfig, `videos/${v4()}`);
  
  await uploadBytes(storageRef, file, {
    contentType: video.mimetype,
  });

  return await getDownloadURL(storageRef);
};
```

You have not shared complete code so I am not sure where you are calling `uploadVideo()` function from but the file must be saved locally to use the above function.

Comment: , I am sending the video data from client to the nodejs and i already send the image what's data is coming from the client

Comment: @KartikFulara can you please edit your question and show where `uploadVideo()` is called from? Also, did you try the solution in my answer?

Comment: I edited the question and also before the current code I used your way it uploaded to the firebase but 0 bytes have been there one more thing when I am not using temp files using your way uploading is working but in Cloudinary image is not uploading @Dharmaraj

Comment: @KartikFulara there is no code related to Cloudinary in your question. The original question states issues with upload to Firestore as well....

Comment: I found the answer thank you